# CloudFoundry - how to get Python 3.5 support in Ruby app

Tags: python, ruby

I have a Ruby On Rails application that I'm deploying through CloudFoundry using the default Ruby Buildpack.

Unfortunately at some point my app needs to execute a Python 3.5 script.

I have already noticed that by default python is in fact provided, but only as version 2.7.

What would be the easiest way to get Python 3.5 support for my Ruby application? (I don't know anything about CloudFoundry buildpacks, I've just been provided credentials to deploy).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that only 2.7 version is supported. What you wanna do is not possible.
But there is very slight difference between Python 3 and 2. If you know 3 then just by simple research you could use version 2. Hope this help.

Comment: I see. Yet python 2.7 is really old now, and it would seem pretty strange to me if it was simply "not possible". I simply cannot use Python 2, it needs to be 3.5...

Comment: Actually, It is not possible now but most probably they will be adding the support of Python 3. And Python 2.7 is old but in a way gold because it is having more library support than Python 3.